# I need to lock row from reading by other transaction

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, jboss

I have requirement where I need to lock rows of table for reading by other Transaction.
Means,
If Transaction 1 reads few records for table 1. These rows should not be read by Transaction2

I am having following environment
1. MySQL
2. Jboss 5.1
3. JPA 1.0

Please let me know your suggestions

I am using native query select for update 
Query createNativeQuery = entityManager.createNativeQuery("select id from cscache where id = ? for update ");

But it is giving following error

2014-12-12 09:35:42,326 ERROR [org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter                    ] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'limit 2' at line 1   (http-0.0.0.0-8543-5:)

Comment: For JPA 1.0, only 2 lock mode is supported, `optimistic read/ optimistic write`, those two modes allow any transaction read and update an entity. It will check at transaction commit time only.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like that.

LOCK TABLES tbl_name  READ;

For more details . please click [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables.html)

Answer (score 0):

SELECT FOR UPDATE should do the trick.

```
YourClass c = em.find(YourClass.class, yourId,
    LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE);
```

or

```
TypedQuery<Table> q = em.createQuery("select t from Table t where ...", Table.class);
q.setLockMode(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE);
```

Comment: I am having JPA1.0 it does not supports LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE

Comment: oh sry. my bad - should try to read more carefully. Is a native query an option (with SELECT ... FOR UPDATE)?

Comment: np...I also looking for select for update..will update you soon